# Custom validation in google forms using Google script on focus out the field

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

Is this possible to check to validate a text field on focus out in google forms? Need to check for the unique value and notify the user about an error.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  But it's not done with code.  Because it's not done with code, this is not a programming question.  So it's "off topic" to Stack Overflow.  The criteria for validating a user answer is done when you make settings in the Form.  You can't write code to validate user input.  If the "built-in" capability doesn't work for you, then there is no other option.  But, the "built-in" capability is quite good.  It can't reference a previous answer as criteria for a subsequent answer, if you need something like that.

Comment: Sandy, thank you for the fast response. Actually, I need to check the that user's answer is unique if compare it with the answers of other users on the same question. If the user 1 answered 'test', the second should be able to type any answer, but 'test'. This can be done by checking the new answer with an array of answers on the same question. But seems google forms allow only on load and on submit events, so seems no way to check on change or something like that. And this can be done only by programming. "Built-in" capability is quite good, but doesn't cover this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google forms allow only onload and onsubmit events, so seems no way to check on change, on blur or something like that. "Built-in" capability is quite good, but doesn't cover this situation.